# Delta-Wye turns ratio

Tags: transformer

Isn't the turns ratio = 11kV / 480V = 23 in the following problem?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Draw out the 3-phase circuit (delta winding and wye winding) and it will be obvious to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The primary is wye connected therefore each primary winding receives 11 kV / 1.732 volts = 6351 volts.
- The secondary is delta wound hence the voltage appearing on the secondary directly comes from a secondary winding.
- This makes the turns ratio 6351/480 = 13.23.